# Stored Procedure without mapping with DbSet

Tags: entity-framework

Can we call stored procedure without mapping with DbSet using Entity Framework Code First approach

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _"without mapping with DbSet"_. Show the code you currently have, and which parts you don't like.

Comment: Do you mean to call a stored proc without mapping it to an entity's CRUD operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw SQL and call the procedure that way.

```
 var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList();
```

or

```
 var blogs = context.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList();
```

Comment: Hi  I have like this - public class PMDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
             
    }
}    How i should call Stored Procedure in Controller .

Comment: var employees = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<Employee>("GetCompanyEmployees @companyId", companyIdParameter);
                .ToList();

You just have to have a n object who has the same property names as the returning procedure result set. (In this case the Employee object)